# Rails remote form HotWire not sending javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

I have an error, the thing is I need to send a remote form, this is my configuration

```rb
<%= form_tag(get_provider_configuration_server_providers_path, method: :post, local: false, data: { turbo: "false" }) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :provider, '', id: 'provider-configuration-value' %>
  <%= button_tag 'Save Deploy Script', style: 'display: flex;', id: 'btn-provider-configuration'  %>
<%end%>
```

and this the javascript I am using

```js
document.getElementById('server_server_provider').addEventListener('change', function() { 
      document.getElementById('provider-configuration-value').value = this.value;
      document.getElementById('btn-provider-configuration').click();
});
```

and this the controller and I have the view get_provider_configuration.js.erb

```rb
  def get_provider_configuration
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

But it is sending the form like a normal form, it means it reload the page.
Any help?

Comment: well I can see a couple of issues... there may be more. You define `data: {turbo: false}` on the form... but you seem to want a turbo response, so I'm not sure why you set `false`. Also, you need to request (i.e. in the form url) a js format, the default will be html.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting local: false you need to set remote: true to make the form submit async